# nwjs reactjs, confused about my context. Document is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-webkit, nw.js

In my **nwjs** application i am using **React** to build my UI. Currently, **React** is being loaded via a `<script>` tag in the main file, index.html. index.html has another `<script>` tag which loads main.js containing code which defines and renders my **React** components as well as requiring (`require()`) a few Node modules such as "fs" and "McFly".

This all seems to be working, however when i try using another node module (react-inlinesvg) i get an error, "document is undefined".

Having looked online for help, i have come to the conclusion that **React** now believes that it is being run on the server? Which is odd, as before i started using the react-inlinesvg module it was happily rendering components using `React.render` (clientside rendering).

**If you need any more context or information then please ask.**

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are rendering on the server side, or also that you are rendering both sides. In the second case you could simple nest the line that is causing you error with:

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
   the line causing the error
}
```

If the error disappears, it means that you are on the server side also!
I hope this helps...

Basically if you code is [universal](https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9) (or isomorphic, if you want...) with this check you can execute the code only on client side, you want to do this to use a particular style-sheet for example:

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
  require("../style/main.scss");
}
```

Naturally if you want to do stuff server-side you can check

```
if (!process.env.BROWSER) {

}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry just to clarify this makes any code within the 'if' run in the browser context?

Comment: It checks if the browser context is true. So I think yes, I'll try to make my answer a bit clearer!

Answer (score 0):

if any one face this he can solve it in 2 ways:

**Solution 1:** if you are using nw.js 15 or above try to enable mix context mode:
in your package.json add this flag:

```
"chromium-args": "--mixed-context"
```

**Solution 2**: expose document to the global object using this hack:

```
global.document = window.document;
```