# NwJS, and requiring client libraries

Tags: javascript, nw.js

I'm building a small app with nwjs, and naturally I want to use some typical client-side libraries.  For example I have in my main app

```
var ko = require('knockout');
```

The problem is, while `document` is defined in my main app, it is not defined in the context of required libraries (I've checked).   Interestingly knockout worked for quite a few things before I ran into an error where it was trying to access `document`.

This seems like a major problem for nwjs, unless I'm missing something.  How are you supposed to use client-side libraries with nwjs?

(FWIW, there was an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555484/nwjs-reactjs-confused-about-my-context-document-is-undefined) on almost the exact same topic, but it involved React.js which seems to have its own server/client behavior so the answers didn't address the basic issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use separate mechanisms to include libraries based on whether they are server-side or client-side.   Server-side libraries can be loaded with `require()`.   Client-side libraries (if they need access to the document environment) need to be loaded with `<script>` tags in the index.html file.

In hindsight it is obvious, but it took me the better part of a day to figure out, so posting in case anyone else has the same confusion...

Comment: In 20 more hours, it will let me do that :-)